# Eliminate repeating lines by calling function

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is there any possible way to eliminate repeated lines by calling a function for many buttons in (aspx.cs) asp.net. I have tried through class, but elements of WebForm cannot be called. Is there any other way?

```
txtDescription.Text = "";
txtProjectDate.Text = "";
rblProjectStatus.SelectedIndex = -1;
txtProjectName.Text = "";
txtWebsiteUrl.Text = "";
calProjectDate.Visible = false;
chkProject1.Selected = false;
chkProject2.Selected = false;
ddlCompanyName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Name--"));
```

This code have to be inserted into a function, so that I can call the function wherever necessary. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can just refactor this to a private helper method in the codebehind and call that, can you not?

Comment: When do you need this function to get called? When the user presses several different buttons?

Answer (score 1):

```
partial class MyPage
{
    protected override void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetControls();
    }

    protected override void MyOtherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetControls();
    }

    private void ResetControls()
    {
        // do your business here
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can hook both buttons to the same handler if they are to have identical behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to reset the form. You should do this way (a button on web page):

```
<input type="reset" />
```

Another alternative is to redirect to the current url (from your C# code):

```
 Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.RawUrl)
```

Comment: Note that `<input type="reset" />` doesn't "clear" all inputs. Instead it resets them to the values they had when this version of the page first loaded. After a failed server-side validation you will go back to the "failed" values.